# General learning question about while loops

Tags: python, while-loop

So for the basic code below. I thought the spam = spam + 1 would be adding 1 to the local variable spam, but it appears to add it to the global ( or else why would you start with the global variable spam = 0) . I thought local variables only exist within the function( starting after the colon.) It seems like this should not work considering local/global scopes?

```
  spam = 0
    while spam < 5:
        print('Hello, world.')
        spam = spam + 1
```

Comment: There's no function here. Functions start with a line `def functionname(parameters):`

Comment: `spam` is sharing the same namespace.

Comment: First of all, your code is not well structured I think, I don't see the point of indent for the `while`. Second, you don't have local variable, `spam` is defined outside of the `while` scope. Last, you don't have a function, the `while` only defines a scope.

Comment: I fully understand and learned from all your input thank you.

Comment: `spam += 1` is more better than `spam = spam + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while` loop doesn't create a new scope. Scopes are only established by function and class definitions. The `while` loop is not a function definition.

So the `spam = 0` and `spam = spam + 1` statements are in the same scope, since there's no function definition around either of them.

Comment: Thank you some much for your positive and direct answer. I know my question was not perfect but your response was so on point to what I needed to learn. I really appreciate that.